# REACT + TypeScript Accordion transition doesn't works

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Sup guys i have a problem, i would like to do an animated accordion, it should to have a transition animated when it opens and collapse, and in icon switching
I'm creating by myself an accordion in react + typescript but this transition doesnt works and idk why, code below:

This my index.tsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { AccordionButton, AccordionContent, Wrapper } from "./styles";
import { AccordionProps } from "./interfaces";
import { BsChevronDown, BsChevronUp } from "react-icons/bs";

export default function Accordion({ title, text }: AccordionProps) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    returnIcon();
  };

  const returnIcon = () => {
    return isOpen ? <BsChevronUp /> : <BsChevronDown />;
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <AccordionButton onClick={handleClick}>
        {title} {returnIcon()}
      </AccordionButton>

      <AccordionContent isOpen={isOpen}>
        <p>{text}</p>
      </AccordionContent>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

and this is my styled component below:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { AccordionContentProps } from "./interfaces";

export const AccordionButton = styled.button`
  background-color: #606582;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.6s;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #60658295;
  }
  > svg {
    float: right;
  }
`;

export const AccordionContent = styled.div<AccordionContentProps>`
  display: ${(props) => (props.isOpen === false ? "none" : "block")};
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
`;

export const Content = styled.div`
  padding: 10px 0px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    max-width: 80%;
  }
`;

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 10px 0px;
`;
```

I've tried to add this code but still doesnt working

```
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
```

Comment: You're calling `returnIcon` inside an event handler - what do you expect it to do?

Comment: its returning and replacing my icon, it worked, i thougth i could economize some code lines, but my transition effect didnt worked :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `return` block with the following:

```
 return (
 <Wrapper>
  {isOpen && <AccordionButton onClick={handleClick}>
    {title} <BsChevronUp />
  </AccordionButton>}
  {!isOpen && <AccordionButton onClick={handleClick}>
    {title} <BsChevronDown />
  </AccordionButton>}

  <AccordionContent isOpen={isOpen}>
    <p>{text}</p>
  </AccordionContent>
</Wrapper>)
```

and we can also delete the function `returnIcon` - we don't need it

Comment: well it worked, i mean, the accordion function is working but the transition effect doesnt

Comment: Try do debug the transition on your browser. I suspect that that instead of drawing another component (BsChevronUp/BsChevronDown) you should draw the same component and attach it a different css className: react doesn't "know" css so it will draw on the screen whatever you'll give it.